# Error while copying files to Hard disk

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive

I am getting this error while copying my files to Western Digital 2TB external hard drive via USB.

I am getting error sometimes when copy is done 30% or 60% or 90%  and I am getting this frequently.

[image]

**ERROR :** `error 0x8007045D : the request could not be performed because of an I/O device error`

I am also checking [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/error-0x8007045d-the-request-could-not-be/17d085c8-bab4-4d31-9a2b-e7a4ba38d387) but I wanted to get more insight in what actually the problem is ? Please help, I am using Windows 8 system, I see this error again and again for different different files. How to fix this?

Comment: sounds like your hard disk is dying

Comment: ;( ....what should I do it is 2 TB HDD ?

Comment: @Sathya : r u sure ? what can i do

Comment: buy a new hard disk

Comment: Back up your data **now**. Then check the smart diagnostics for your disk.= and buy a new one if necessary.

Comment: thanks for comment !!!! is there any possibility that it may have happened because of OS probably ?? ... or you all are sure its because of external hard disk